# Php download script argument - path to filename

Tags: php

I have a quick question regarding a download script used on one of my sites:

Basically the script is embedded into a download button for a downloading a specific file. However the script accepts arguments like so: `download.php?="filename"`.

If however i change the argument in the browser to force the script to download a file from a different directory like "`images/map.jpg`" it simply tries to download a file called `"images-map.jpg"`. Any idea why? What should be the correct argument?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you not to use direct link to the file - it is not safe. It is better to map it somehow and implement header level redirection to the file.
Second - use urlencode() when passing arguments by GET method.
And the last - please make print_r($_REQUEST['GET']) to see what is being sent to the server. It can be configuration issue of the Web Server as well as an attempt to implement your request for something like: http://site.example/download.php?=images/somefile.img - in this way, web server will try to open somefile.img as a file, not passing this parameter to the php script.